# Before actions in Sails controller

Tags: orm, sails.js, waterline

Is there a way to have an action/function executed before each and all actions defined in a Sails controller? Similar to the `beforeCreate` hooks in the models.

For example in my DataController, I have the following actions:

```js
module.exports = {
  mockdata: function(req, res) {
    var criteria = {};

    // collect all params
    criteria = _.merge({}, req.params.all(), req.body);
    //...some more login with the criteria...
  },
  getDataForHost: function(req, res) {
    var criteria = {};

    // collect all params
    criteria = _.merge({}, req.params.all(), req.body);
    //...some more login with the criteria...
  }
};
```

Can I do something like the following:

```js
module.exports = {
  beforeAction: function(req, res, next) {
    var criteria = {};

    // collect all params
    criteria = _.merge({}, req.params.all(), req.body);
    // store the criteria somewhere for later use
    // or perhaps pass them on to the next call
    next();
  },

  mockdata: function(req, res) {
    //...some more login with the criteria...
  },
  getDataForHost: function(req, res) {
    //...some more login with the criteria...
  }
};
```

Where any call to any action defined will pass through the beforeAction first?

Comment: Use policies instead, it will make your code looks clearer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use policies here.

For example, create your custom policy as `api/policies/collectParams.js`:

```js
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
    // your code goes here
};
```

Than you can specify if this policy should work for all the controllers/actions, or only for specific ones in `config/policies.js`:

```js
module.exports.policies = {
    // Default policy for all controllers and actions
    '*': 'collectParams',

    // Policy for all actions of a specific controller
    'DataController': {
        '*': 'collectParams'
    },

    // Policy for specific actions of a specific controller
    'AnotherController': {
        someAction: 'collectParams'
    }
};
```

Sometimes you may need to know, what is the current controller (from your policy code). You can easily get it in your `api/policies/collectParams.js` file:

```js
console.log(req.options.model);      // Model name - if you are using blueprints
console.log(req.options.controller); // Controller name
console.log(req.options.action);     // Action name
```

Comment: Great! Thanks.
One more addition to this. It is possible to chain policies in a defined order. As per the docs instead of adding a specific policy, you can add an array e.g. to the edit method `edit: ['isAdmin', 'isLoggedIn']`

If an action is explicitly listed, its policy list will override the default list.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use policies as a beforeAction.

The docs show that its used for authentication, but It can basically be used for your purposes. You just put your before action in a policy.

http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/Policies

Comment: Thanks for the link. As described in @Leestex answer this looks like the solution.